# I have a trouble in using pip and easy_install on windows. (Python 2.7.9 & 2.7.13)

Tags: python-2.7, pip, package, easy-install

I have a trouble in using pip.

I was struggling for two hours to solve the problem, but I could not.

Firstly, my OS is windows 8

At first I downloaded python 2.7.13, but there was no script folder in Python 27 when I downloaded it, so I deleted and downloaded 2.7.9.

Still there was no script folder in Python 27 after downloading python 2.7.9. Fortunately, I found the scripts folder in tools folder, but there was no pip.py or pip.exe or so on.

I thought my python did not have default pip like others. So I tried to download pip. One way I found in internet was to download the get-pip.py file and execute using

```
                python get-pip.py
```

But, when I did, it showed me this error. (I used admin prompt)

[image: image description here]

I don't know what is the problem..  Please tell me what I should do..

Answer (score 0):

First, Install python in your windows machine run .msi,  i.e microsoft installer.
that will create `c:/python2.X/script`automatically once successfully installed in your system.

Refer this links for more details.
https://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/

[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)